# Bounty tooltip shows same name multiple times

Tags: bug, bounties, tooltips

I just noticed this issue on the bounty tooltip of [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93541):

---

[image]

---

> This answer has been awarded bounties worth 150 reputation **by Rand al'Thor and Rand al'Thor**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

I understand that the user has awarded two bounties on this answer, but displaying the name twice still seems a bit odd to me. The plural of *"bounty"* is enough to deduce that, in my opinion.

First I thought that maybe another user in this community has the same name, but [searching all users](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=rand+al%27thor) only returns one result. Of course there is a possibility this user's account was deleted, but I think the chance of that is not *that* high to not ask this here.

**Edit:** The [question history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/93537/revisions) proves that both bounties were awarded by the same user.

---

I know it's a minor bug, but can this please be fixed so that each user can only be mentioned once in the bounty tooltip?

Comment: Who would be interested in knowing who awarded a bounty and how many times? I have never seen the tooltip on any bounty before and I didn't know it could be awarded twice by the same user. I don't think the tooltip itself is necessary.

Comment: So *that's* why I have multiple personalities ...

Comment: [Another occurrence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342788/202324).

Comment: [And again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364656/146438).

Comment: [And again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372186/146438).

Comment: [It's pretty common](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/134655/32746).