# Is there any user satisfaction data for other SE sites than Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, community

A lot has been written and said about users finding Stack Overflow unwelcoming.  For example, see [The Loop 2: Understanding Site Satisfaction](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019/) on the weblog, or *[What about the community is "toxic"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342779/172266)* here on Meta SE.

Is there any survey data for user satisfaction on other SE sites than Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 7):

I am not aware of any specific "other network site/community" survey data.

But maybe, just maybe, we could run [our own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342834/would-it-be-helpful-if-the-user-community-defined-its-own-survey-and-publish) survey!