# Would it be helpful if the user community defined its own "survey", and "publishes" that as a meta question?

Tags: discussion, meta, community

I just came across [Is there any user satisfaction data for other SE sites than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342832/is-there-any-user-satisfaction-data-for-other-se-sites-than-stack-overflow) and I think, most likely, the *bleak* answer will be: no, there is no *official* survey data that explicitly covers other sites on this network.

Leading to a *crazy* (?) idea (somehow resembling something that user [Renault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/205798/s%C3%A9bastien-renauld) inspired in a different place):

- We users could sit together and design a (small) set survey of questions.
- That questionnaire could then be published as a meta question, and users could then "fill out" that questionnaire.

We could start doing this here on MSE. And in case it works, other communities could pick up our questionnaire, and adapt it accordingly, and then run a "local" survey on their individual meta sites.

<s>Two</s> Three questions:

- Would "doing exactly that" be within "on topic"? Or are there legitimate reasons/policies that prevent us from doing it like that?
- If it is allowed, is it a *good* idea?
- Or would you prefer to try to convince SE Inc. to run "our" survey through "their" channels, as outlined in comments below?

---

<sub>Sure, that wouldn't be the same as a "real" survey: answers are tight to a username, automatic processing/evaluation would be hard. But it would be something under "our" control, and it would enable *any* community member to look at the raw data.</sub>

Comment: CM Jon Ericson once created one for Sound.SE: [Where do we go from here? Take the survey!](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324/21060)

Comment: Apart from the question if this is allowed on meta, would the results tell us something? An issue I see is that a user survey wouldn't have the same large audience like an officially announced one, so that could mean that only users who are interested in such a user survey will participate and the results aren't able to tell us something about the overall perception of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' That is good to know. The downside is: it depends on an individual, or a small group of people to *build* something like that. You also need a server, consider privacy, whatnot. The big advantage of doing it here is ... it is all out in the open.

Comment: @Tom We could still try our best to announce it too as many people as possible ...

Comment: Yes of course, I just wonder how reliable the data will be. We sadly can't tell how visible the announcement was and if it reached a broader audience to get representative data. The amount of people taking the survey might be an indicator. It would be great to get a mod onboard to get a `featured` tag, that would help.

Comment: @Tom We definitely need mods onboard on the various site-specific metas, but I suspect that will be no problem at all.  If some sites don't want to survey then they simply don't, we're not forcing any site to participate.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer if the company would circulate this survey in the same manner they circulate their customer satisfaction survey? We would just design it, they would circulate it and return the data after the survey is finished and then we analyze it. It should just clearly be marked as not an official survey by the company.

Comment: @Trilarion If the community would decide they wanted to go forward with this, I can raise it at the internal moderator team site; I have the impression there is a better chance of getting someone from SE to actually read it (perhaps due to the higher signal to noise ratio compared to Meta SE).

Comment: @gerrit Makes sense, I updated my question to include this as third option.

Answer (score 21):

We can do this.  We can use a community wiki post to design the survey questions, but let's not use Q&A to conduct the survey.  It's the wrong tool.

There are plenty of free alternatives online for conducting surveys, such as [SurveyMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SurveyMonkey) (we may have to search around if their free plan doesn't meet our needs, perhaps we can find a volunteer to host a survey on their own personal server).  We would just need volunteers to host the SurveyMonkey (or other) survey under their personal account and publish the raw results somewhere (possibly stripped of responses that might identify users if there are any open questions), and would then need volunteers to process the results.

One issue would be the balance between anonymity vs. fraud-resistance.  It's not possible to guarantee both, so we'd have to choose which one is more important to us.

Another issue would be representativeness, but that is true for any survey and there's no way getting around that.  It would be up to each site to feature an announcement of the survey and hoping to get a good response.

Comment: I was under the impression that survey monkey would only work when you throw money at them. There is a "free plan", but that restricts you to *view* only the first 100 responses for example.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Oh, that could be, I've never gotten close to 100 responses to surveys I did there.  A dedicated survey for a smaller site would be happy to get close to 100 responses, but if we do a single cross-SE survey we would indeed need something where we can gather a larger number.

Comment: i doubt it'd be difficult to find someone willing to sponsor such a survey.

Comment: @user400654 Well, reception here hasn't been negative, but also not overly excited either.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of mechanics (there was some discussion of Survey Monkey) -- the easiest approach in my experience is a Google Docs Form.

I like your idea very much.  If support grows for this idea, you could next post a question where you collect suggestions for specific questions.

Related:

[Academia Community Polls](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/467/32436)

[Where do we go from here? Take the survey!](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324/20367)

[Survey of users to judge quality and culture of an SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308753/287826)

Comment: NB. Google is blocked in China.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones - Bummer.  Do you know what would work there?