# AI to use grammar syntax for auto-flagging comments

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

We were having a titillating discussion in the Teacher's Lounge about toxic comments when it came up that "imperatives" could indicate rude comments. I won't defend this, but I'll explain the background...

Take this made-up comment:

> Edit your post so it has sources.

That's "imperative", instructing someone what to do. To new users, that may seem bossy. We mods on BH.SE use comments that sound more like suggestions. Albeit, different sites have different cultures... tl;dr

Then, we discuss more...

**Adding "please"** doesn't make it less bossy, but seems more friendly. Is it?

> ***Please*** edit your post so it has sources.

Then, we discuss more...

**Adding conditionals** appeals to logic and feels less bossy. Consider what I've seen others post, and myself:

> Please edit your post to include sources ***so that others don't vote to delete it***.

...The imperative alone (first example) may be perceived differently than the imperative with the conditional (third example)...

Maybe you don't agree. Great! Maybe you do agree, but before we get married...

## tl;dr

***Using pure grammar*** in our considerations, alongside other considerations, could be very helpful. We could look at meaning, buzz words, et cetera. But, also step back and take a look at the pure grammar itself.

That could be useful because:

1. Grammar is objective and thus is a better reason for flagging, voting, deleting, taking action, et cetera.
2. Grammar could work with AI to more easily auto-flag possible abusive comments.

I don't want to argue whether asking a user to edit a comment is abusive. I want input on using *pure grammar itself* as a possible way be more objective, *both for community human decisions and for AI* helping out with the grunt work.

*We are discussing this because we [want to be more welcoming to new users](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4121/how-can-we-be-more-welcoming-to-new-users), in the minds of high-reps [on more than one site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328269/should-i-be-nice-to-new-users/328271#328271), as [the network can be perceived as toxic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342779/what-about-the-community-is-toxic-to-new-users). Perhaps running grammar through AI algorithms might help identify trends from comments in the past that were deemed abusive. This presumes that we are looking for ways to be more welcoming.*

Albeit, comments would be easier to implement, but once refined it could prove useful for flagging posts and beyond.

Comment: Have you heard of [The Unfriendly Robot: Automatically flagging unwelcoming comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/09/the-unfriendly-robot-automatically-flagging-unwelcoming-comments/). Not sure how good it was, but the idea already occurred, only without using pure grammar.

Comment: My personal catch phrase when commenting with the aim to improve a question is "This question should ...". But it rarely does really afterwards, so I'm not doing it often.

Comment: Maybe if robots focused on grammar more and we focused on grammar less, we'd all be more friendly in casual chatter. lol :-)

Comment: One more idea: Let AI reformulate comments to make them "more friendly and helpful" and then with A/B testing find out it that really works (i.e. if the question edit rate by the OP really is increased or if the next question of the OP is received significantly better than in a control group).

Comment: I'm contemplating [hijacking that as an answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931/9517). :-P lol #love

Comment: ...and that comment can't be deemed "rude" because it's not in the imperative. lol

Comment: I'm actually not sure that grammar alone is sufficient to determine the helpfulness of a comment. My guess is that even with the perfect manners and grammar there could be pretty annoying comments or conversely helpful comments that only lack the right grammar. So I'm a bit skeptical, but I don't want to dismiss the idea either. I would rather see it in action (the company should have a really large dataset of millions of friendly and unfriendly comments annotated by mods to test every possible hypothesis) before judging it. Maybe somebody like Kevin Montrose could run something there.

Comment: Anyone who believes that tone in English can be deduced from grammar without context is probably wrong.

Comment: For example, I could post *Do. Or do not. There is no try.* as a joke based on comments that have gone before. I could post *Yes, please do tell me how I can improve. I do truly enjoy it when experts on the Internet correct me.* as rude sarcasm based on what went before. Also, do we have AI that can effectively parse English grammar written by random people of mixed levels of fluency? You could probably catch some folks' canned comments that could use some softening, but you don't need to parse grammar for that.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the imperative in general. I use it a lot in sentences like "see [link]", "note that Y", or "sign into X" (as an instruction). There is something more going on when you ask someone to edit (no idea how to describe it... is "bossy" the right word?). For the record, I don't see "adding conditionals" as improving the sentence. It feels too much like a threat to me. Ultimately, the specifics of what a person finds rude or not is highly culturally dependent.

Comment: Terse does not imply rude.

Comment: Having moderated on ELL for several years, I agree with @Laurel about the subjectivity of rudeness. The language barrier has often caused some misunderstandings about whether someone is being rude. The only cure for that is an engaged community where people feel free to ask "Hey, did you mean to call me an idiot, or did I misunderstand?" and where other users will try to help explain things when comments seem be misunderstood because they are too terse. Removing marginally/potentially unwelcoming content is not as effective as adding friendly content.

Comment: Words like "alone" and "only" aren't any part of this suggestion. While mood doesn't imply tone without context; absent words refuted are called "straw men".

Comment: @VLAZ "Terse does not imply rude." It could still correlate with it. The company has millions of annotated unfriendly comments. If we can somehow define terseness, we could maybe learn something about how terseness is received.

Comment: I didn't downvote your suggestion, but I still don't understand why you think grammatical structure can be used to assess tone "objectively". I can say "Watch it buddy, or you'll get what's coming to you." and adding the conditional actually makes it more unfriendly. I think we can use AI to help screen comments. I think grammar is not the right metric for this environment.

Comment: @ColleenV Honestly, the reason it makes sense to me is that I'm both a coder and a writer. So, in preparing the AI algorithms and telling an AI what to look for, throwing grammar into that mix would give AI programmers a lot of very useful things to focus on building out. In their programming work, it would *never* be the only consideration at all, nor would it be right for any kind of first and final decision; it would simply be a useful factor for them to explore over years and decades.

Comment: @Laurel Wow! Loaded with truth. Adding conditionals wouldn't always make it better, it would just be one more factor to explore as programmers build out the AI's processors. It would be nothing like, "User X used an imperative; ban for life." But, really... Do we consider how many imperatives vs subjunctives we use in a repartee? When we kerfuffle, we aren't even thinking much at all, just reacting. AI aside, if we humans considered not just our tone, but mood of verbs, that might have a stronger calming effect than "counting to 10". Feel me?

Comment: English grammar does not convey tone. It's a framework we hang our meaning on to try to get it across to another person more easily, but we don't really need it. Just look at textspeak or [doge](https://the-toast.net/2014/02/06/linguist-explains-grammar-doge-wow/). Most people can understand doge without knowing the grammar of it, but the tone may elude them if they don't understand the context. Also, you're a hopeless optimist if you think most of the comments here are grammatical ;)

Comment: Also you need to consider culture. To me as a Dutch person a direct comment like your first example isn't "wrong" at all. While in other cultures it might be perceived as problematic.

Comment: @Luuklag The "truth" about right and wrong comments would be what moderators think it is. So it would depend on the culture they are coming from, whatever that is.

Comment: @Luuklag I strongly agree, having lived in Taiwan 13 years. So, any AI algorithms should look for indications that the writer is not a native speaker—and we moderators should also.

Comment: "*So, in preparing the AI algorithms and telling an AI what to look for, throwing grammar into that mix would give AI programmers a lot of very useful things to focus on building out. In their programming work, it would never be the only consideration at all, nor would it be right for any kind of first and final decision*" The question left me with the impression that ***only*** grammar would be used. So, is that not the case? What is the question actually about?

Comment: @VLAZ That considering grammar as one more indicator among many could be useful. AI software makes billions of calculations per second. SE has a site dedicated to AI because it factors so many variables and considerations. There's no way that any worthy AI would only consider a few factors. They are always looking for more things to consider in their difference engines.

Comment: "could be very helpful" is hardly an extreme black-and-white paradigm.

Comment: "*That considering grammar as one more indicator among many could be useful*" The question very clearly states "*Using pure grammar*" and never actually claims that it'd be used alongside other factors. And to me the word "pure" means that it *would not be* used with other factors. So, if the question is "should grammar be one of the factors used to consider comments" then my only response would be to shrug and say why not. Factors tend to be weighted to produce the final decision on something. If less helpful the weight would be less. Not sure what is there to discuss if just a hypothetical.

Comment: I get you, I feel you. Thank you.

Comment: @VLAZ How do you like that edit. I feel I've expressed myself more thanks to your observstion. <3

Comment: Seems more clear. But also not sure what is there to discuss, really. Let's say the community says "Yes" or a "No". It doesn't matter since such a system doesn't exist. And if such a system is made, the creator does not need to abide by what the community said anyway.

Comment: @ColleenV "English grammar does not convey tone." Why not? Maybe there is statistically a bit of a deviation for the grammar usage between good and bad tones. Grammar is a structure on the language. ML projects are all about structures in data, so if we feed the structure better into an ML system for example by detecting and providing used grammar as additional inputs, it might perform better. Maybe even simply because the understanding of the content gets better.

Comment: @VLAZ no rules are proposed here, only something to discuss in making both rules and AI tools. Nor, does my OP propose a heavy-handed force over everyone. I see there is a lot of objection from many users to things I neither believe nor my OP says.

Comment: @ColleenV everything is grammatical by definition, the quesiton is how? Grammatically correct? Grammatically wrong? Vernacular? Region-specific? Bilingual (ie what some call "Chinglish" or "Spanglish" or other errors when borrowing grammar from one language to mistakenly use in another)? It seems you think a group of words only has grammar if it is correct, which isn't true. Comedians use style-specific grammar in preparation to imitate speech from various regions. All words use grammar, right, wrong, or purple. So, there is always grammar to identify.

Comment: Some pronouns in comments should be banned altogether. Using them in whatever way makes it about the user, not the content. Stack Exchange is about content, not users. Thus here is a good use of the passive voice, even if it has been villainised (e.g., [Grammarly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammarly) is said to be obsessed with it). E.g., *"The post may be considered to be changed from X to Y because of Z."*

Comment: It may also be considered developing a set of *approved* and *effective* comment structures that will tread/tromp on nobodies' feet (I am not sure if the last part is an idiom in English).

Comment: FI, an example of [an approved canned comment for a common occurrence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) is (the post is ***moderator locked*** and all–it can hardly get any more official)—and I am quoting: *[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)*

Comment: [Grammatical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammatical) : conforming to the rules of [grammar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grammar), a system of rules that defines the grammatical structure of a language. By saying "everything is grammatical", you've just illustrated my point of how difficult finding patterns associated with tone in the grammar of comments written by a global, mixed-fluency community is.

Comment: Grammar carries meaning not tone. Any grammatical structure can be used to be rude or welcoming, and because we are a global community, we can't rely on the "most people understand *this* to mean *this*", or for a good baseline of what is considered unfriendly.

Comment: *Any grammatical structure can be used to be rude or welcoming* is a scientific claim with trillions of possible permutations and needs scientific backing; this is an assertion without evidence.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: Seems fine to me. Including the link in the comment shows that it's a policy that's been discussed & decided upon, & not the mere whim of an individual user who's got too big for his boots; & that the person the comment's directed at is thought to deserve an explanation rather than expected to unthinkingly comply.

Comment: Give me one grammatical structure that is always undeniably rude regardless of what words I put in it. If I can't make it not-rude, I will concede your point.

Comment: It *needs research*, further research, not just our anecdotes, and the premise here is about grammar patterns in a context. We'd need a chart to discuss with thousands of entries.

Comment: @JesseSteele My assertion is easy to disprove. All it takes is one construction that is rude to most people on Stack Exchange no matter what words I put in it.

Comment: Proving isn't the point, it's what to research. Proof comes after inquiry, reporting findings comes after experimentation, not before.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum how does this relate? It looks like you are refuting or defending imperatives. From my opening paragraph: *I won't defend this, but I'll explain the background* and from the closing: *I don't want to argue whether asking a user to edit a comment is abusive. I want input on using pure grammar itself as a possible way be more objective*

Comment: Logic (the formal kind, not the I-has-common-senses kind) doesn't require research to make provable assertions. Neither does math. If you assume there is such a thing as grammar, and that we can detect whether something is "unfriendly" we don't need research to determine if my assertion that I can make any grammatical structure not-unfriendly just by word choice.

Comment: I observe that there are uncountable unstated presuppositions when we discuss proposals for uncharted exploration.

Comment: Yeah, and all you need is one to prove I'm full of crap. That you can't think of one doesn't support my point, but it doesn't disprove it either. This isn't a trial, I'm just sharing what I know to be true in a discussion. I'm not saying your idea is dumb, I'm just saying that I think you're heading down a path that isn't productive.

Comment: @Jesse Steele: I am not refuting or defending anything. I am only interested (and I think a lot of other users are too) in not inadvertently getting banned for some comment (especially canned comments) that could have been phrased in a different way. I will follow any decided policy to the letter. It would be much easier with a fixed comment structure.

Comment: Here is a question I asked when I was fairly new to the site that might have some food for thought [How to review without being perceived as picking on people](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348/9161) People perceiving comments as unfriendly is an issue, and we should think about ways we can reduce the number of times people misconstrue a comment the author thought was neutral as something unfriendly, either by educating the author or by managing the reader's expectations.

Comment: But a lot of guessing is involved. A survey (or interviews to reveal the real motives), that would include users from ***all*** parts of the world, could reveal more information. For instance, it could be the lack of addressing and the lack of greetings in *every* comment that is the real problem ("cold" and "impersonal"). *"Hey brodette, it is a nice day outside. Could you perhaps please look into X? It looks like Y is Z."*. The survey could also involve, for each common occurrence that is be to covered, say, 10 different canned comments of which one is to be chosen as the preferred.

Comment: @ColleenV We've deliberated. Would you please formulate an answer for how destructive and damaging it could be. Even if they proceeded, you've got a lot of amazing points that need considering. Answer with this, please.

Comment: I'm supposed to be working right now deciphering an algorithm that is recursive and changes the code on the stack as it does its thing so I can locate a bug. I don't currently have the mental bandwidth to do more than comments lol. I fully support anyone who wants to "steal" my comments and work them into an answer; I'll come back later to clean them up. I'm kind of surprised how much I rely on knowing where I am on the call stack to figure out what's going on. The person who wrote this code is either a genius or insane :)

Answer (score 14):

You use three imperatives in this very post:

> Take this made-up comment

> Consider what I've seen [...]

> Step back and take a look [...]

That no-one would consider these examples  rude in the least must already cast considerable doubt on the notion that the use of the imperative mood might provide a purely syntactical indicator of rudeness without regard to semantics.

A cursory survey of comments on the site I moderate suggests these kind of what you might call rhetorical imperatives are very common. Most other occurrences of imperatives aren't in instructions to do something or other on the site, and many of those that are appear in implicitly or explicitly solicited advice (e.g. how to get a certain symbol with MathJax).

Here's an example where someone *is* being instructed to take a particular action:

> Please do not give new information only in comments, edit your
> question to add the new information. We want posts to be
> self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, information in
> comments are not well organized. Also, many people do not read
> comments.

Even if there were only the first, imperative, sentence, it'd hardly be *rude*; & it wouldn't be more polite when recast as a question ("Would you please not [...]"): what makes it considerate, though, is taking the trouble to explain the reason in the following sentence. You allude to something like this, I think, in your discussion of conditionals,<sup>†</sup> but again the grammatical form employed to this end seems barely relevant.

Not to throw the baby out with the bathwater: there are cases where using the more direct imperative rather than a more indirect form can seem rather bossy, but they're very context- (& culture-) dependent. And directness is sometimes called for: it's not a desirable outcome that someone ends with up their question closed/account suspended for ignoring "If you ask me, it might be a good idea if you were perhaps to [...]".

For someone already set up for training M.L. models on S.E. comments labelled as rude or not, I don't suppose it'd be all that much effort to investigate a little, *if* there's an off-the-shelf P.O.S. tagger that can identify imperatives. I don't know if there is or not: the one in OpenNLP, for example, uses the  Penn English Treebank, & would tag an imperative as a "base form" of a verb, along with infinitives. If there isn't, it's a question of whether this looks a promising enough avenue of investigation to develop one specially—in view of what I've written above, I don't think so.

---

†
Your example, however, comes over more as a threat or a warning than an explanation:

> Please edit your post to include sources so that others don't vote to
> delete it.

More welcoming is:—

> Please edit your post to include sources so that interested
> readers have something to follow up (or skeptical ones can verify your
> claims!).

Comment: It's about comments, not questions or answers, right there in the title. Applying it to questions or answers is a later possibility, described in the closing sentence.

Comment: I don't say this to be rude because I have done the same thing. I'm looking for ways to improve. My above comment could have been written by an AI and delivered before the Answer was posted. Such a feature would have saved me from many great embarrassments in the past.

Comment: I understand, but such phrases are of the kind  people commonly write in comments too. I just didn't have to search too far for examples of what you might call rhetorical imperatives - that aren't exactly issuing orders.

Comment: My point exactly! So, as AI writers work to take the grunt work load off of mods, they could identify which may need moderator attention by grammatical patterns, not just a list of "unfriendly phrases". Research might reveal something there we could learn from.

Comment: I don't understand the thinking that the statement "Let's explore space" could mean "Everyone burn your houses if you don't live on the USS Enterprise D". I think questions about possible progress inherently make us imagine the worst, then we react as if our imaginations aren't imaginary.

Comment: "Let's explore space" - "Er ... do you have a rocket-ship?" - "I have a trampoline" - "Let's go to the pub". It's more like that. I don't believe you've made a good prima facie case that grammatical features would be of much use for auto-flagging comments, compared to obvious ones like vocabulary, for the reasons I give - which are of course themselves only prima facie reasons. I don't contest that "research might reveal something there we could learn from"; but that's not a strong claim.

Answer (score 1):

This is not snark. I'm flat serious.

## Easy-to-misunderstand Questions may be a greater priority

This Question may be off-topic since it presumes what some might call "hyper-geek" knowledge, or specialized knowledge, which is why I put out a [feeler for asking on AI](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/can-we-ask-whether-how-ai-might-be-applied-to-a-specific-need-or-use).

As a writer, I'm supposed to make sure others understand my words. By that standard, this is a terribly written OP because ***it gives some readers the wrong impression that:***

- it proposes applying rules with a heavy hand (it doesn't)
- it would exclude all other considerations (it wouldn't)
- it is about Questions and Answers (it isn't, that's possible future)

For example, this comment probably should have been inside the OP:

> So, in preparing the AI algorithms and telling an AI what to look for, throwing grammar into that mix would give AI programmers a lot of very useful things to focus on building out. In their programming work, it would never be the only consideration at all, nor would it be right for any kind of first and final decision; it would simply be a useful factor for them to explore over years and decades.

The system could have picked up that I talk about AI, but that is a technical industry that not everyone understands. So, a post for people who are experienced in fields other than AI would benefit from this explanation on a site that is not about programming, (like Meta, Worldbuilding, and Writing.) But, it might be patronizing on sites about programming (like Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Unix & Linux, and especially the AI site).

That might have been really great to have the pre-question system give me a notice like

*"Some users might not understand your Question because it assumes specialized knowledge from another field. Consider providing a brief explanation."*

## The proposed OP may still have some priority

The proper answer from a researcher might be that *AI should search "deemed-abusive" comments for grammatical patterns, looking for any trends,* only then could we know whether it is useful.

Comment: I don't want to edit the OP too much because I think my bad example makes for great research. Hanging myself out to dry for the team.

Comment: It may be considered that "OP" in these quarters is normally *only* used for "original poster" (not "original post" as in some other online cultures).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Yep, for sure. I've seen it to be coterminous both ways.