# Why are Stack Exchange sites too complicated to understand?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, help-center

There isn't any way I can get around in any of the Stack Exchange site. Do sites demand technical background and more professionalism?

Comment: Many sites have very little to do with technology e.g cooking or vegetarianism ,& veganism. They all require you to do research into what is on/off topic and none of them like questions as vague as this one.

Comment: What's vague about this one?

Comment: So basically I have to go through rules of each site of stack exchange I visit?

Comment: Usually, just taking the [tour] is enough.

Comment: @AbdulMoiz it's vague because we don't know anything about you so we can't say what your problem is, only by providing details could you make that possible. Millions of people successfully use these sites so we don't know what your problem is, only you can tell us. Also, if you've problems with your existing questions then you need to ask on a per-site meta rather than here.

Comment: If the "sites" here are "too complicated to understand" then please give an example of one such site.

Comment: What do you mean by *"get around"*? Is it about a ***particular*** incident? Being question banned or downvoted? Can you provide one or more examples? Preferably, by [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/393481/edit) your question. But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum why so many " *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***"?

Answer (score 9):

This is... not an easy question to answer. The sites in Stack Exchange network (typically) require some degree of professionalism, yes. That said, a decent amount of expectations from a "be nice" point of view are [in the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Different sites require different tasks. To provide a detailed answer, to, say, a Java question on Stack Overflow, chances are you'll need some understanding of Java. There's also many sites that don't require a technical background, such as, say, Gardening Stack Exchange. So all sites certainly don't "demand" it, but it *can* be useful on some of the more technical sites, yes.

In regards to your title, that's somewhat of a challenging question. Stack Exchange (for the most part) is quite different than other sites. We have *far* more rules, and *far* faster and stricter moderation compared to, say, Reddit. This isn't true of all sites, but it's certainly true on some of the larger sites, like Stack Overflow. To quote Mithical in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342788)

> There is a really steep learning curve for the site. Stack Overflow is, objectively, really different from most sites on the internet. We don't take subjective questions. We don't allow open-ended requests. We don't allow polls. We don't even allow posts about computers that aren't directly programming.
>
> If you arrive from Reddit or Quora, you're going to encounter a massive culture shock. It's just so different in what's acceptable here.
>
> So when someone arrives, and they post something that would be acceptable anywhere else on the internet, and within ten minutes they've been downvoted twelve times, had their question closed so that nobody can answer, and had three comments telling them that their question wasn't acceptable... that's frustrating, to say the least.
>
> It takes a bit to learn how to properly ask a question on SO - and to learn when a question would fit better on SU or SF, for example. In the interim, you get slammed with downvotes and closures and comments. It's easy to feel attacked.

Although I realize it isn't exactly what you're asking, I'd actually suggest reading [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342788) (the rest of what I quoted) fully. No guarantees, of course, but it may be helpful.

Comment: Also, if what the question author means by "professionalism" is that the site is geared specifically at professionals in the field - that's true of some SE network sites, but there are plenty of sites whose audience includes amateurs, enthusiasts, and learners as well.